# Do we have a Grauert-Fischer theorem for non-trivial families?

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, deformation-theory, several-complex-variables

This question is related to my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450107/is-an-isomorphism-between-holomorphic-vector-bundles-still-holomorphic-with-resp). Let $X$ be a compact complex manifolds and $\Delta\in \mathbb{C}^n$ be a small neighborhood of $0$. A family of deformations of $X$ over $\Delta$ is a complex manifold $\mathcal{X}$ together with a proper holomorphic submersion $\pi: \mathcal{X}\to \Delta$ such that $\pi^{-1}(0)$ is biholomorphically isomorphic to $X$. Notice that in general the fiber $\pi^{-1}(t)$ is $C^{\infty}$-isomorphic to $X$ but not biholomorphically.

Two families of deformations of $X$, $\pi:  \mathcal{X}\to \Delta$ and $\tilde{\pi}:\tilde{\mathcal{X}} \to \Delta$ are called equivalent if there exists a biholomorphic isomorphism $\phi: \mathcal{X}\overset{\sim}{\to} \tilde{\mathcal{X}}$ such that $\phi\circ \tilde{\pi}=\pi$ and $\phi|_{\pi^{-1}(0)}=\text{id}_X$.

Now we can loose the condition: Consider a $C^{\infty}$-isomorphism $\phi: \mathcal{X}\overset{\sim}{\to} \tilde{\mathcal{X}}$ such that

1. $\phi\circ \tilde{\pi}=\pi$.
2. $\phi$ is a biholomorphic isomorphism when restricted to a fiber of $\pi$ at any $t\in \Delta$.
3. $\phi|_{\pi^{-1}(0)}=\text{id}_X$.

We call such  $\phi$ a $C^{\infty}$-equivalence between $\mathcal{X}$ and $\tilde{\mathcal{X}}$.

> > My question is: when $\Delta$ is small enough, if there exists a $C^{\infty}$-equivalence between two families of deformations of $X$, is it always true that there exists a equivalence between them?

Notice that if $\tilde{\pi}:\tilde{\mathcal{X}} \to \Delta$ is the trivial deformation, i.e.
$\tilde{\mathcal{X}}=X\times \Delta$ and $\tilde{\pi}$ is the projection to the second component, then the above result is implied by the *Grauert-Fischer theorem*:

"For a family of compact complex manifold  $\mathcal{X}$ over $\Delta$, if each fiber $X_t$ is biholomorphically isomorphic to $X_0$, then $\mathcal{X}$ is biholomorphically isomorphic to $X_0\times \Delta$."

But I am not sure if the similar statement is true for non-trivial families. By the way, I don't have the access to Grauert-Fischer's original paper *Lokal-triviale Familien kompakter komplexer Mannigfaltigkeiten* so I cannot see if their proof could be generalized to this case.

Comment: See this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.11395 by Kirschner for a discussion and some useful references (including work of Wehler https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01360031 for families of tori, and of Meersseman http://www.numdam.org/item/10.24033/asens.2148.pdf, which Kirschner challenges).